# how does wappalyzer detect javascript libraries?

Tags: javascript, php

I've made a tool using Wappalyzer in PHP. My wapp.php can detect many technologies but comparing to Wappalyzer itself, mine can't detect all js libraries and technologies. I've searched all information in header, files, page content, etc. wapp try to match patterns and keywords in those areas. But I don't know where it looks for js techs. To make it more clear, I've cases that there is no sign of a library anywhere in the page and my tool doesn't detect anything too, but wapplyzer detect some js techs like google analytics.

Answer (score 0):

They are analyzing data from our http response or headers .Please check the wappalyzer code base : https://github.com/AliasIO/wappalyzer/blob/5f629ad25a24694e6b1ab7bb60b8b5b565846d09/src/technologies/p.json#L19

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30892850)